Opening champagne on Shabbat - untwisting the metal
Somewhat related to this question. (Open bottles shabbos)
In order to open champagne bottles one first has to untwist the metal tie.

"Everybody" seems to open champagne on Shabbat - and the Shmirat Shabbat Kehilchato doesn't mention it in his chapter about opening various bottles and containers. (Chapter 9)
If twisting metal is a type of sewing, then untwisting it should be like ripping, also forbidden on Shabbat.
So, why is this permitted on Shabbat? (sources appreciated).

dinonline answers your question here

It is permitted to open and close then on Shabbos. Although there is controversy regarding twist ties, if they may be opened and closed
on Shabbos. Most authorities hold that it is permitted, and although
some people are stringent with this, the halacha is that essentially
it is permitted.
Additionally, this case is even better than that, because here you are
not fashioning anything, because the metal is already wound together.
You are only tightening and loosening the already wound tie. Therefore
everyone would agree in this case that it is permitted. Additionally,
the bottom ring is similar to a lock that is evident that it is made
to open and close constantly, and therefore permitted.
Sources regarding twist ties: Emes L’yackov ftnt. 360, Divrei Yatziv
O:CH 152, Ohr L’tzion 2 chap. 29-2, Shevet Halevi 8-55, 10-61, Chut
Shani Shabbos 2 pg. 228, Igros Moshe and Beer Moshe quoted in The
Shabbos Home 14 ftnt. 12, Orchos Shabbos 10 ftnt. 51, Am Mikadshei
Sheviei 2 chap. 5 ftnt 37, Megillas Sefer 21-6, Nitei Gavriel ( Erev
Pesach On Shabbos) 17-18. SS”K 16 ftnt. 174

